# jquery datatables display product link in table

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I am using jquery datatables to display a large amount of data with child rows and individual column filtering etc....    I am importing all of my data via a json txt file.    I need to be able to link the part numbers(parent row) in the table directly to the corresponding product page.

**EDIT:**  Based on Tims response below, I've edit this post with the new information

New txt file sample:

```
{
"data": [
  {
    "PartNumber": "201008", 
    "PartUrl": "99-05-sonata-optima-santafe-catalytic-converter.aspx",
    "LongDesc": "Direct-Fit Converter",
    "Year": "2002",
    "Make": "HYUNDAI",
    "Model": "SANTA FE",
    "Engine": "2.4L/2351cc L4",
    "Thumb": "images/products/thumb/201008.jpg",
    "Location": "Front"
  },
  {
    "PartNumber": "201008", 
    "PartUrl": "99-05-sonata-optima-santafe-catalytic-converter.aspx",
    "LongDesc": "Direct-Fit Converter",
    "Year": "2003",
    "Make": "HYUNDAI",
    "Model": "SANTA FE",
    "Engine": "2.4L/2351cc L4",
    "Thumb": "images/products/thumb/201008.jpg",
    "Location": "Front"
  },
```

Here is where I added it to the js file:

```
 /* Formatting function for row details - modify as you need */
function format ( d ) {
// `d` is the original data object for the row
return '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;padding-right:50px;">'+
    '<tr>'+
        '<td>Category:</td>'+
        '<td>'+d.LongDesc+'</td>'+
        '<td rowspan="3"><img src="' + d.Thumb + '"/></td>'+
    '</tr>'+
    '<tr>'+
        '<td>Location:</td>'+
        '<td>'+d.Location+'</td>'+
    '</tr>'+
    '<tr>'+
        '<td>Notes:</td>'+
        '<td>'+d.Notes+'</td>'+
    '</tr>'+
'</table>';
}

$(document).ready(function() {
 // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
$('#example thead th').each( function () {
    var title = $('#example thead th').eq( $(this).index() ).text();
    $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
} );

var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    "ajax": "../data/cat-datab.txt",
    "columns": [
        {
            "class":          'details-control',
            "orderable":      false,
            "data":           null,
            "defaultContent": ''
        },
        { "data": "Year" },
        { "data": "Make" },
        { "data": "Model" },
        { "data": "Engine" },
        { "data": "PartNumber" }
    ],
"columnDefs": [ {
"targets": 5,
"data": "PartUrl",
"render": function ( data, type, full ) {
  return '<a href="'+data+'">'+PartNumber+'</a>';
}
} ],
    "order": [[1,'asc'], [2,'asc'], [3,'asc'], [4,'asc'], [5,'asc']],
    "bSort": false,
    "bPaginate": true,
    "bLengthChange": true,
    "bInfo": false,
    "bAutoWidth": true,
    "iCookieDuration": 60*60*24, // 1 day 
} );

// Add event listener for opening and closing details
$('#example tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
    var tr = $(this).parents('tr');
    var row = table.row( tr );

    if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
        // This row is already open - close it
        row.child.hide();
        tr.removeClass('shown');
    }
    else {
        // Open this row
        row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
        tr.addClass('shown');
    }
} );

   // Apply the filter
$("#example thead input").on( 'keyup change', function () {
    table
        .column( $(this).parent().index()+':visible' )
        .search( this.value )
        .draw();
} );


} );
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Year</th>
            <th>Make</th>
            <th>Model</th>
            <th>Engine</th>
            <th>Part #</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Now the table will not render at all and I get a console error in the browser, it returns an error of

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: PartNumber is not defined
```

I hope this helps clear it up.

Thanks for your assistance.

**UPDATE:  Fixed**

It was pretty easy actually.   I reformatted the child row and added a View Product Page link next to the picture.

```
 function format ( d ) {
// `d` is the original data object for the row
return '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;padding-right:50px;">'+
    '<tr>'+
        '<td>'+d.PartNumber+'</td>'+
        '<td><a href="' + d.PartUrl + '" target="_blank">View Product Page</td>'+    
        '<td rowspan="4"><img src="' + d.Thumb + '"/></td>'+
    '</tr>'+
    '<tr>'+
        '<td>Category:</td>'+
        '<td>'+d.LongDesc+'</td>'+
    '</tr>'+
    '<tr>'+
        '<td>Location:</td>'+
        '<td>'+d.Location+'</td>'+
    '</tr>'+
    '<tr>'+
        '<td>Notes:</td>'+
        '<td>'+d.Notes+'</td>'+
    '</tr>'+
'</table>';
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `aoColumnDefs` and `mRender`. For example:

```
"aoColumnDefs": [
            {
                "mRender": function (data, type, row) {
                    var $href = $("<a></a>").prop("href", data);
                    return $("<div/>").append($input).html();
                },
                "aTargets": [4]
            }
```

This would render a link using the data passed in for the 4th column if memory serves me right. It has been a little while since I used this and I just grabbed snippet from an old project.

**EDIT**
It has been a while since I use datatables, things have changed - the above example may only work with an older version of datatables. See [this demo](http://www.datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/column_render.html) for a good working example. `columnDefs` and `render` should do the trick.

From the demo:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "columnDefs": [
            {
                // The `data` parameter refers to the data for the cell (defined by the
                // `data` option, which defaults to the column being worked with, in
                // this case `data: 0`.
                "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
                    return data +' ('+ row[3]+')';
                },
                "targets": 0
            },
            { "visible": false,  "targets": [ 3 ] }
        ]
    } );
} );
```

Comment: Thanks for the direction.  It didnt work for me but I am sure that it is something I am doing wrong.

Comment: I posted my edit before the info you posted from the demo showed up.  I am not sure I understand how the code you pasted will help me add a link into the displayed data, but I used the example in the demo from adding links and reposted my new info above, returning an undefined error, explained in my edit above.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. Sorry I did not see this sooner to help. As I am sure you figured out, the "render" function allows you to basically define a template, which can include any element(s) you like. Also, you can access other pieces of data via the `row` array: `row[0]` for example.

Answer (score 0):

At following link: 
https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data#

If you can check following example:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "columnDefs": [ {
    "targets": 0,
    "data": function ( row, type, val, meta ) {
      if (type === 'set') {
        row.price = val;
        // Store the computed dislay and filter values for efficiency
        row.price_display = val=="" ? "" : "$"+numberFormat(val);
        row.price_filter  = val=="" ? "" : "$"+numberFormat(val)+" "+val;
        return;
      }
      else if (type === 'display') {
        return row.price_display;
      }
      else if (type === 'filter') {
        return row.price_filter;
      }
      // 'sort', 'type' and undefined all just use the integer
      return row.price;
    }
  } ]
} );
```

it manipulates the first column depend on type and value. you can target second column and manipulate content using data function in columnDefs parameter.

Hope this helps.